# What kind of DLC did Toyota's have before switching to OBDII?

Tags: toyota, obd-ii

What kind of DLC did Toyota's have before switching to OBDII?  What year did they switch to OBDII outside the United States?

Comment: i forget the number of pins but they have 2 connectors sometimes one under hood which can still be seen in early 2000's cars and a round connector that was under the dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a picture of the two different types of connectors Toyota used for their DLC.

[image]

The square one is marked DLC-1 and the round one is DLC-2. I believe DLC-1 was accessed under the hood. You can see the connection end in this picture.

[image]

The connector in this picture is connected to the left side strut tower. The round connector was (I believe) accessed from the driver's compartment. I'm not sure when companies switched over to OBD-II outside of the US, but believe it was for the most part around the same time as it occurred in the US (1996 is the start for OBD-II in the US). I would bet this was highly dependent upon if the particular vehicle model was exported to the US or not. Common sense would dictate a company would not engineer two solutions when one would do, but that is speculation on my part.

Comment: Mazda kept using their proprietary connector outside the US until 2000 on many of their vehicles, such as the 626.  Same with Nissan.  They used the Consult-II interface until at least 1999 outside the US.  By the way, any idea what PC based software was used with these Toyata's?

Comment: Good question ... not really sure. I've not done much diagnostic work beyond reading codes on Toyotas.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes It was a handheld deal. I'm unsure if there were PC based solutions.

Comment: @Ben That sounds odd.  There are a ton of PC based solutions for the Nissan Consult-II interface from those years.  Maybe Toyota's weren't so popular with do it yourselfers?

Comment: Some interesting info:  http://toyota.kgbconsulting.ca/wiki/OBD-1_Serial_Interface

Comment: Found a site with software and technical info:  https://zainalarif.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/toyota-dlc1-dlc2-datalogger/

Comment: Found something relevant on aliexpress: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Best-Sale-MINI-VCI-V10-00-028-For-Toyota-Lexus-Scion-TIS-Techstream-OBD2-USB-Cable/32645949621.html?spm=2114.13010308.0.0.f8MaKK